# Finding triplets having highest common relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two types of nodes in my graph. One type is Testplan and the other is Tag. Testplans are tagged to Tags. I want most common pairs of Tags that share the same Testplans with a Tag having a specific name. I have been able to achieve the most common Tags sharing the same Testplan with one Tag, but getting confused when trying to do it for pairs of Tags. The cypher returning the list of single tags is shared below

```
MATCH (kw1:Tag)<-[e:TAGGED]-(tp1:Testplan)-[e2:TAGGED]->(kw2:Tag) 
WHERE kw1.name = "result"

RETURN kw1,kw2,count(tp1)

ORDER BY count(tp1) DESC
```

This cypher returns something as follows

```
Kw1                   kw2                       count(tp1)
“result”              “error”                   104
“result”              “prerequisites”           89
“result”              “alpha”                   63
```

I want the result to be

```
Kw1                   kw2                           count(tp1)
“result”              “error”,”prerequisites”       70
“result”              “error”,”alpha”               63
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll have to elaborate what you want. 1) The count in your second result makes no sense w.r.t. the data (should be sum of 104 and 89 for first result and sum of 104 and 63 for second result). 2) What exactly is the meaning of the second result ... would the line "prerequisites, alpha" also be in that list ?

Comment: Count in the second table implies testplans having all three words. Hence number is not sum. But testplans common to all three.@TomGeudens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (kw1:Tag)<-[e:TAGGED]-(tp1:Testplan)-[e2:TAGGED]->(kw2:Tag),
(tp1)-[:TAGGED]->(kw3:Tag)
WHERE kw1.name = "result"
AND ID(kw2)<ID(kw3)
RETURN kw2, kw3,count(tp1)
ORDER BY count(tp1) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
This works nice.Thanks a lot for sharing. However, just to follow this up, in place of two if I want 3/4/5 such combinations, what should be the ideal way? I tried to tailor the query without understanding much, but this is making Neo4j crash even on a high performance computer.
The query I attempted is as follows

MATCH (kw1:Tag)<-[e:TAGGED]-(tp1:Testplan)-[e2:TAGGED]->(kw2:Tag),
(tp1)-[:TAGGED]->(kw3:Tag),
(tp1)-[:TAGGED]->(kw4:Tag)
WHERE kw1.name = "result"
AND ID(kw2)<ID(kw3)<ID(kw4)
RETURN kw2, kw3,kw4count(tp1)
ORDER BY count(tp1) DESC

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily fix this using `collect()`

```
MATCH (kw1:Tag)<-[e:TAGGED]-(tp1:Testplan)-[e2:TAGGED]->(kw2:Tag) 
WHERE kw1.name = "result"
WITH tp1,collect(kw2) as tags,count(*) as count
RETURN tags,sum(count)

ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it is not working. To explain it briefly, let's  say I have 10 Testplans which have relationship with "result". I am looking for Tags other than "result" which commonly co-occur in those Testplans.
For example "prerequisites" and "error" might be present in the same 8 of 10 Testplans whereas "prerequisites" and "alpha" may be present in the same 5 of the 10 testplans. I am attaching the result of you query in my question as edit.

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error saying "mismatched input '(' expecting { ';'......}"

Comment: In this use case, `distinct(tags)` should be replaced by just `tags`, since the grouping key (`tags`, in this case) for an aggregation function (`count()`) is automatically made distinct internally anyway. More importantly, when you specify the `DISTINCT` operator, it is applied to *all* the returned values -- the parentheses around `tags` do NOT limit that operator's actions to just `tags`. This subtle fact may not make a difference to the results of this specific query for this specific use case, but in general it could.

Comment: Still not getting the right result. The output of the query is added to the question as an edit. I am looking for only pairs of Tags that come with "result" in the same testplans. So if B is a tag that comes in 5 testplans with "result" and A is a tag that comes with "result" in 10 testplans but A,B and result together come in only 3 testplans then the count should be 3. I am looking for such combinations in decreasing order of frequency

Comment: tried something else... not sure why it doesnt group as it should.. maybe this will work

Comment: Somehow, this is also not working

Just to give you an idea of my graph. there are 122 testplans having relation to "result". But the edited query that you have shared is showing the image that I have attached in the question. The problem is that the highest count returned is 222 which is not making sense. Need to thank you for being so helpful