# Getting most frequently occurring pairs of co-actors with an actor in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question is nearly same as [Finding triplets having highest common relationships in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541495/finding-triplets-having-highest-common-relationships-in-neo4j)
But the answer provided is not solving the purpose. 
My database has two types of nodes. Movies and Actors.
I want to find the most frequent pairs of co-actors for a given actor. So, if an actor has acted in 100 movies, I want to find most common pairs of co-actors in those 100 movies.

```
Database type
(:Movie)-[:STARS]->(:Actor)
```

I can get the most frequent co-actors in a list of descending order by frequency following the CQL

```
MATCH (actor1:Actor)<-[st1:STARS]-(mv1:Movie)-[st2:STARS]->(actor2:Actor) 
WHERE actor1.name = "Tom"

RETURN actor1,actor2,count(mv1)

ORDER BY count(mv1) DESC
```

mentioned in the question itself. But the answer posted is not returning me with pairs of co-actors
The answer I am looking for is as follows

```
Actor1  Actor2  Actor3  Count(Movie)
A         B       C          20
A         B       D          10
```

This table can hypothetically imply that A has starred in 25 unique movies and in those movies B and C are together as well in 20 and B and D are together in 10